# How to get a vertical line in math mode in Springer Nature Template

Tags: math-mode, equations, springernature

I am trying to get the following equation:

[image]

To do so, I am using the code as shown below:

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbf{P(W|T)}$
\end{document}
```

However, this results in:

[image]

What can I do to get the desired equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code :

```
$\mathbf{P(W\vert T)}$
```

I tested it with the `sn-jnl` template on Overleaf.

---

To remove the whitespace, you can also use:

```
$\mathbf{P(W{\vert}T)}$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put `\def |{\vert}` in front of `\begin{document}`. Then `$\mathbf{P(W|T)}$` will work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the `sn-jnl.sty`.

This works (on my machine):

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{scrreprt}% <<< class  
\begin{document}  
    $\mathbf{P(W|T)}$ % unchanged 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please indicate relevant changes next time. Here I added just two comments, as at first glance both codes look the same, don't they?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Andrew. Your approach does not work for me and raises many errors for the rest of the document.